# freebsd driver to hook mi_switch

Tags: kernel, hook, freebsd

if I wanted to hook **sys_read** then I could use **sysent[SYS_read].sy_call** to hook the function.

But how can I hook **mi_switch**? no other way than run-time kernel memory patching?

with run-time memory patching I assume I should add an instruction and call my syscall from mi_switch.

Comment: From user space or from kernel space? mi_switch is not a syscall, it is internal to the kernel.

Comment: yes exactly that's the problem, it's not a syscall :D no difference for me, wanna patch it from either user space or kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

A possible but really dirty trick could be to set kdb_active and call kdb_jumpbuf()
to manipulate kdb_jmpbufp.
Then let the longjmp() in kdb_reenter() end in your function.